# Form and dynamically generated button JavaScript not working

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am facing a problem with a form on my website. I have a form that works correctly when it exists on the page initially, but when I try to dynamically generate this form via JavaScript, the form does not perform any action when submitted.

When you press the button `<button type="submit" class="generate-btn">Generate IA</button>` it does not do any action

My form has the following structure:

```
segundoDiv.innerHTML = '';

var nuevoElemento = document.createElement('section');
nuevoElemento.className = 'image-generator';
nuevoElemento.innerHTML = `
        <div class="content">
            <form action="#" class="generate-form">
                <input class="prompt-input" type="text" placeholder="Describe what you want to see" required>
                <div class="controls">
                    <button type="submit" class="generate-btn">Generate IA</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <section class="image-gallery">
            <div class="img-card hiddenia"><img src="images/img-1.jpg" alt="image"></div>
        </section>`;

// Agregar el nuevo elemento dentro del segundo div
segundoDiv.appendChild(nuevoElemento);
```

This is the script that does not run:

```
<script>
const generateForm = document.querySelector(".generate-form");
const generateBtn = generateForm.querySelector(".generate-btn");
const imageGallery = document.querySelector(".image-gallery");

const OPENAI_API_KEY = "12345678910"; // Your OpenAI API key here
let isImageGenerating = false;

const updateImageCard = (imgDataArray) => {
  imgDataArray.forEach((imgObject, index) => {
    const imgCard = imageGallery.querySelectorAll(".img-card")[index];
    const imgElement = imgCard.querySelector("img");
    const downloadBtn = imgCard.querySelector(".download-btn");
        imgCard.classList.remove("hidden");

    // Set the image source to the AI-generated image data
    const aiGeneratedImage = `data:image/jpeg;base64,${imgObject.b64_json}`;
    imgElement.src = aiGeneratedImage;
    
    // When the image is loaded, remove the loading class and set download attributes
    imgElement.onload = () => {
      imgCard.classList.remove("loading");
      downloadBtn.setAttribute("href", aiGeneratedImage);
      downloadBtn.setAttribute("download", `${new Date().getTime()}.jpg`);
    }
  });
}

const generateAiImages = async (userPrompt, userImgQuantity) => {
  try {
    // Send a request to the OpenAI API to generate images based on user inputs
    const response = await fetch("https://api.openai.com/v1/images/generations", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Authorization": `Bearer ${OPENAI_API_KEY}`,
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        prompt: userPrompt,
        n: 1,
        size: "1024x1024",
        response_format: "b64_json"
        
      }),
    });

    // Throw an error message if the API response is unsuccessful
    if(!response.ok) throw new Error("Failed to generate AI images. Make sure your API key is valid.");

    const { data } = await response.json(); // Get data from the response
    updateImageCard([...data]);
  } catch (error) {
    alert(error.message);
  } finally {
    generateBtn.removeAttribute("disabled");
    generateBtn.innerText = "Generate";
    isImageGenerating = false;
  }
}

const handleImageGeneration = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  if(isImageGenerating) return;

  // Get user input and image quantity values
  const userPrompt = e.srcElement[0].value;
  const userImgQuantity = 1;
  
  // Disable the generate button, update its text, and set the flag
  generateBtn.setAttribute("disabled", true);
  generateBtn.innerText = "Generating";
  isImageGenerating = true;
  
  // Creating HTML markup for image cards with loading state
  const imgCardMarkup = Array.from({ length: userImgQuantity }, () => 
      `<div class="img-card loading">
        <img src="images/loader.svg" alt="AI generated image">
        <a class="download-btn" href="#">
          <img src="images/download.svg" alt="download icon">
        </a>
      </div>`
  ).join("");

  imageGallery.innerHTML = imgCardMarkup;
  generateAiImages(userPrompt, userImgQuantity);
}

generateForm.addEventListener("submit", handleImageGeneration);</script>
```

I thank you for your helP

The script is not executeD

Comment: *The script is not executed*; which script, exactly, isn't executed?

Comment: You APPEAR to want to put HTML in something referenced as `segundoDiv` however that is never defined and NOT in your JavaScript code..

Comment: hey OP, can you please post your question with a snippet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is probably coming from the way you listen to the form `submit` event. You do it once and for all, on page load, and this will only work if the form is already in the page when the following code is executed:

```js
const generateForm = document.querySelector(".generate-form");
// ...
generateForm.addEventListener("submit", handleImageGeneration);
```

A simple solution would be to execute the code above again after the new form is dynamically added to the page, to grab the new form and add the event listener to it.

Another solution, especially useful in the case you would have the same form multiple times on the page, would be to delegate the event listener to a parent element, like the `document` and check if the submit event occurred from a `form` you actually care about:

```js
// Add the listener on the `document`
document.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  // Check if its a form used for the image generation
  if (event.target.matches('.generate-form')) {
    // In this case run the generation
    handleImageGeneration(event);
  }
});
```

Here’s an example using the same event listener for many forms: https://jsfiddle.net/msze18n5/5/